# Recover Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sql, sharepoint-2007

here is the scoop:

- have backups of all config and content databases
- do NOT have master and msdb backups

Need to restore baseline functionality ASAP. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: try following -> make fresh installation -> restore your content databases.

Comment: sure, but what about all the jobs and logins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just add the SharePoint login to the instance with sysadmin rights, then restore the databases and start the application.  SharePoint doesn't do much to the instance other than creating the "delete expired sessions" SQL Agent job.  As long as the SQL server instance name is the same SharePoint should come back up.

Comment: yes, we did just that and it worked. Any idea how to recover the SQL Agent job?

Comment: Yes, create a SQL agent job through SSMS that runs the stored T-SQL command "EXECUTE DeleteExpiredSessions" in your ssp_service SharePoint database (not sure hwat your's is named but it probably has that text in it), then schedule it to run every minute.